# Can I work for food delivery apps as a tourist in the US?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, work

If I want to go to USA to do a certification exam but in this time I want to do some deliveries for apps like GrubHub or Doordash, can I legally do this with a B-1/B-2 visa or with the Visa Waiver Program?

If the answer is no, somebody can tell me if the government bothers with immigrants working on food delivery apps?

Note: specifically delivery apps.

Comment: No, you clearly can’t. And they will most probably ask for an SSN you don’t have.

Comment: @jcaron this rarely stops illegal immigrants... but it's definitely against numerous laws.

Comment: The answer is obviously No.

Comment: officially, you need a work permission for that. B1/B2 will not give this permission.

Answer (score 10):

**No, you legally cannot do this.** Work means any kind of work, and work is not allowed under B1/B2 or VWP.

> Does the government bother with this.

Yes, if you are caught doing this you will certainly face deportation, and therefore a ban on visiting the US for a long time. If you are eligible for VWP you will lose that eligibility. Even if you are not banned you will face huge difficulties in ever visiting the US again.

You may get lucky and not be caught, but comparing the benefits (getting a small amount of money) with the possible penalties (being unable to visit the US for a very long time) it's not worth it.

By the way, the term 'immigrant' usually refers to someone living in the US for a long time. If you are on a B1/B2 or VWP you are a 'visitor'.

Comment: Deportation triggers a ban, so you could remove "almost certainly."  Also, from a legal perspective, visitors are a subset of "nonimmigrants" as defined at [8 USC 1101(a)(15)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1101#a_15).

Answer (score 6):

No. All of the gig economy jobs will ask for a W9 document that asks you to attest that you have authorization to work in the USA (which you don’t) and your social security number (which you don’t have). The driving apps will also ask for your American driving license which in most states cannot be obtained with a visitor’s visa.

Furthermore, if it’s found out that you’re doing this or even thinking of doing this (say a CBP Officer checks your phone, your email or social media, or your bags), you’ll be kicked out of the USA and given a ban on entry.

0/10 would not recommend.

Comment: I think you mean an [I-9](https://www.uscis.gov/i-9) document.  If OP previously had work authorization, he might have a social security number, but of course that doesn't change the answer.

Comment: @phoog W-9 is correct. "Gig" workers are independent contractors, paid via 1099, so they do not need a I-9.

Comment: @user71659 hm. I've done a lot of 1099 work, but never encountered a W-9 before.